# How to find values of specific variables in a text file using bash

Tags: bash, variables, text

I have a tab delimited results file containing thousands of rows with results.
Each row contains hundreds of different variable in the following form:

```
50001=1 50002=45 50003=-34 50004=MATCH 50005=0.2354
50001=0 50002=167 50003=5 50004=NO_MATCH 50005=2.65
```

I need a bash script to go over the file and gather all the values of one specific variable and the count of appearances, for example:

```
50004 - 1000 appearances total.
MATCH - 600 appearances.
NO_MATCH - 200 appearances.
PARTIAL_MATCH - 200 appearances
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I removed the '...' - it was just meant to clarify that there are several hundreds of variables after the example. About the logic, I don't really care as long as the script gathers the responses and lets me analyse them.

Comment: You want to show stats for the right-hand values? or the left-hand codes? or both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution might be:

```
## replace with 'cat your_data_file'
function show_data {
cat << EOM
50001=1 50002=45 50003=-34 50004=MATCH 50005=0.2354
50001=0 50002=167 50003=5 50004=NO_MATCH 50005=2.65
EOM
}
## include '=' sign to avoid '-'  issue
function simple_grep {
show_data | grep -c "=${RHV}"
}
## change '-' to wildcard '?' otherwise error if '-' first char
function mod_grep {
show_data | grep -c "${RHV/-/?}"
}
##

## option to show matches so you can confirm
if [[ "$1" == "show_matches" ]] ; then SHOW_MATCH=1 ; shift ;  fi
## which grep solution to use
if [[ "$1" == "mod" ]] ; then USE_MOD=1 ; shift ;  fi

### change ' ' to '\t' if tab-delimited
### create unique list of 'right-hand' values
for RHV in $(show_data | tr ' ' '\n' | awk -F '=' '{print $2}' | sort | uniq)
do
        printf "%15s | " ${RHV}
        if [[ ${USE_MOD} ]]
        then
                mod_grep
        else
                simple_grep
        fi
        if [[ ${SHOW_MATCH} ]] ; then show_data | grep  "${RHV/-/?}"  ; echo "##" ; fi
done
```

:)
Dale